# Error after changing Django database from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, easy-thumbnails

I have changed an existing database for a Django project from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL and moved all the data with `dumpdata` and `loaddata` commands. When I'm running the server, It's giving me the following error -

`ContentType 19 for <class 'easy_thumbnails.models.ThumbnailDimensions'> #233 does not point to a subclass!`

I'm using django-filer which has a dependency on easy_thumbnails. I'm guessing the error is coming from there.

I have checked [this link](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/issues/202) and followed teewuane's answer to reorder the django_content_type table but still no luck.

Edit: Tried excluding contenttypes and auth.permission by using -

`python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json`

After loading this data into a new created PostgreSQL database, the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Error fixed by using `--natural-foreign` and `--natural-primary` flags with `dumpdata` command.

`python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json`